# React Deployment with IIS on windows server

Tags: reactjs, iis, production, windows-server

hiii, does someone have experience in deploying a react app with IIS on a windows server? I have everything set up:

In my wwwroot I have the files of react build folder. However, my /api routes are not getting recognized.

I read that the URL Rewrite should solve that issue.
Therefore I installed URL Rewrite and added in my client/public folder the web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
     <rules>
        <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url=".*" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
   </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

However, now I am getting the error of an internal server error and my URL Rewrite tells me that the configuration is not in the right XML format.
Any advice out there?

Comment: Edit the question and show us the actual error page please. Besides, if you search 500 and IIS URL Rewrite module you can find tons of existing threads.

Comment: please post more details information about your error, what error message did you get after deployment? and the best way to deal with xml format issue is to go step by step and comment out certain sections of web.config and application host.config file and check for application behavior. So if the application still continues to throw an error after you have commented a section, then the error is elsewhere. Keep doing this and you will finally arrive at the section that is malformed.